# Create HTML visualization from Brat format

Tags: ruby, visualization, brat

I have a set of files `<*.txt, *.ann>` in [brat format](http://brat.nlplab.org/index.html).

Example: file.txt

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Morbi varius sapien ut vestibulum ornare. 
Donec volutpat ipsum dolor, eu feugiat ligula hendrerit vel.
```

Example: file.ann

```
T1  TagName1 7 11   ipsum
T2  TagName2 19 21  sit
T3  TagName3 23 26  amet
R1  belongs Arg1:T1 Arg2:T2
R2  provides Arg1:T3 Arg2:T1
```

Is there any Ruby gem or parser or library that can produce a highlighted visualization in simple html format of text based on .ann file? Is there someone who has worked with brat file format?

Comment: Brat seems to be able to export the data to SVG or PDF. Maybe that's already enough for you.

Comment: You can use brat's "embedded" setup to let brat render an SVG element for you (which can be done inside a HTML that you are displaying). However, brat rendering is only done clientside, and the algorithm is rather convoluted; I would be very surprised if someone went to the trouble of reproducing it in a serverside gem (which ups the difficulty significantly, given that brat uses the browser's measurements in order to perform its layout).